# List element pattern matching in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

The following pattern matches only the first element

```
{a, b, c, d, e} /. {start : ___, x_, stop : ___} :> {start, 1, stop}
```

How do I make it match all of the list elements?

UPDATE:

The slightly more extended version of my goal is to have a set of three transformation rules for different elements of the list. One rule should apply to the first element, one for the last element, and another rule for every element in the middle. Here's an example:

```
{a, b, c, d, e} /. {most : Repeated[_], x_} -> 
   {most, "Last"} /. {x_, rest : Repeated[_]} -> {"First", rest}
```

These are the rules for the first and the last element. Now I need the rule for all the elements in the middle. Hence my original question.

I've probably chosen a wrong approach, because I cannot find a straightforward way to do this. Is it possible to do this with rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may do:

```
list = Range[10]
list /. {first_, middle__, last_} -> {f[first], g[middle], h[last]}
```

Out

```
{f[1], g[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], h[10]}
```

Or if you define:

```
g[x_, y__] = {g[x], g[y]} /. List -> Sequence
```

Then the result is

```
{f[1], g[2], g[3], g[4], g[5], g[6], g[7], g[8], g[9], h[10]}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your question is a bit unclear. Just guessing what you meant - this will force the longest match:

```
In[2]:= {a, b, c, d,  e} /. {start : Longest[___], x_, stop : ___} :> {start, 1, stop}

Out[2]= {a, b, c, d, 1}
```

While this will give all possible outcomes of rule application, not just the first that matches:

```
In[3]:= ReplaceList[{a, b, c, d, e}, {start : ___, x_, stop : ___} :> {start, 1, stop}]

Out[3]= {{1, b, c, d, e}, {a, 1, c, d, e}, {a, b, 1, d, e}, {a, b, c, 1, e}, {a, b, c, d, 1}}
```

HTH

Edit:

Responding to a more refined version of the question, a generic answer would be

```
{a, b, c, d, e} /. {start_, x__, end_} :> {f[start], g[x], h[end]},
```

Where, by specifying  the functions `f,g,h` one can do any kind of transformations separately on the first, last, and middle elements. Sometimes you can use rules inside rules to make it more concise, for instance:

```
In[7]:= {a, b, c, d, e} /. {start_, x__, end_} :> {start /. _ -> "First", 
                   Sequence @@ Replace[{x}, _ -> 1, 1], end /. _ -> "Last"}

Out[7]= {"First", 1, 1, 1, "Last"}
```

But the main point is that once you have destructured the list, it does not matter what you use to transform the different parts - rules again, or functions, etc - you are not confined to only use rules at that point.

Comment: Actually I wanted to get {1, 1, 1, 1, 1} as a result. So the rule would be applied to all of the list elements.

Comment: @Max: Then, this is just a wrong pattern. Patterns like yours are used for somewhat different purposes, namely when the pattern must capture some non-local inter-dependencies between  elements. Such patterns also often induce significant overhead, and are sometimes tricky to get right as well. So they must be used sparingly. In your case, given your goal, the list elements are pretty independent, so I would do this: `Replace[{a, b, c, d, e}, _ -> 1, 1]`

Comment: @Leonid Shifrin Well, it's not really my goal. It's just a simple example to demonstrate how I want the pattern to work. Actually what I want is to have a set of 3 different transformation rules. One for the first element, one for the last and one for every element in the middle. I had no problems with patterns for the first and the last element. But I couldn't invent a pattern for the middle elements.

Comment: @Max well, then you did not clearly state your goal in the question, at least I find it hard to connect your original request with your latest formulation. Perhaps, this is closer to what you need: `{a, b, c, d, e} /. {start_, x__, end_} :> {f[start], g[x], h[end]}`. Note that you should use a single underscore for the first and last element, to single them out. You can then specify what `f,g,h` are, particularly `g` can convert each of the elements in a sequence to `1` and return the sequence of ones

Comment: @Leonid Shifrin. Is it possible to do it in such a way that g[] takes one middle element at a time, rather than all the elements at the same time?

Comment: @Max: `g` is just a wrapper. It initially accepts all middle elements, but you can make it process them one by one. See the update to my post - since `g` is totally arbitrary, it will do with your elements what you instruct it to. What you ask to do directly is also possible, but will likely be very inefficient for large lists.

Comment: @Leonid Shifrin Efficiency is not a problem because the lists are just 100 to 1000 elements long. I was hoping to put all the transformation rules in one place.

Comment: @Max: Without knowing more specifically what you want, it is hard to give a specific advice. If you want it in one place, you can use pure functions for `f,g,h` from my answer. But I would not worry about this so much. As I said, once you decomposed the list, you are not forced to keep using only (local) rule-based constructs for further parts processing. In fact, in many cases this does not make much sense.  Also, you may be surprised, but for lists of the sizes you mention, using patterns with double and triple blanks *may* become a problem, especially if you use them with ReplaceRepeated.